# Adding OR statements to Eloquent Queries

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need a little help regarding the syntax of Eloquent. I want to add more `where` clauses but can't get the `OR` working. I read https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses but my statement fails.

Works:

```
$events = DB::table('events')->select('id','resourceId','title','start','end')
  ->whereDate('start', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end', '<=', $end)->get();
```

Does not work:

```
$events = DB::table('events')->select('id','resourceId','title','start','end')
  ->whereDate('start', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end', '<=', $end)
  ->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->whereDate('start', '<=', $start)
          ->whereDate('end', '>=', $end);
    })
  ->get();
```

Is `orWhere` not supposed to work with `whereDate`?

Comment: Do you mean the error or the query logic ?

Comment: My question is about the correct syntax for multiple `orWhere` clauses for `date`, not about the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First; while using closures you need to pass arguments with `use`. You may `or` two main conditions and in their nested conditions both sub-conditions will be `and`ed.

```
public function index()
{
    DB::table('events')
        ->select('id', 'resourceId', 'title', 'start', 'end')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
            $query->whereDate('start', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end', '<=', $end);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
            $query->whereDate('start', '<=', $start)->whereDate('end', '>=', $end);
        })
        ->get();
}
```

This function will print (don't mind about the dates, just example)

```
SELECT `id`, `resourceId`, `title`, `start`, `end`
FROM `events`
WHERE (date(`start`) >= '2020-06-15' and date(`end`) <= '2020-06-16')
   or (date(`start`) <= '2020-06-15' and date(`end`) >= '2020-06-16')
```